# Xcode GIT Can't Copy New Files

Tags: xcode

I just installed Xcode 4.2 and now can't copy a new image file to my project. It has something to do with GIT and I've pasted the error below, but I can't seem to find an answer with Google. Can someone please shed light on this?

```
The operation could not be performed because the file is not under version control.
```

Comment: I think you have not added it to the server

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect that the copy failed first then you get the error about version control as a red herring, did you select to copy the file to a location that you have both permissions and space for? If so add the file yourself to your project in the file system, then add to your project, see if you still get that error.