# The file is not under version control

Tags: xcode, git

I'm using a Git. When I add a file and check "Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)" this error occurs:

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7777950/1126111

Answer (score 2):

Try adding it to your project folder and then drag-and-drop to the project in Xcode.

If it still doesn't work you can just create a new file in the project itself, call it the same as the file you are trying to copy and then copy-paste all the code.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the file reference from the XCode. Make sure not move file to trash. Then add the file again by drag and drop or by Add file to project option. Now the file will be under source control.